# Exception handling in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, exception

How to handle exceptions manually in symfony2 in case like this:

```
class Foo {

    // ..

    public function __toString()
    {
        try {
            $this->render();
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            // log $e
            // handle $e - display 500 error page in prod mode
        }
    }
}
```

Redirect? But how.

**EDIT**

My solution so far is to dispatch exception event, and it works.

```
$dispatcher->dispatch(KernelEvents::EXCEPTION, $event)
```

But i requires creating an event. Is there some better solution?

Comment: Is the Foo class a Symfony controller or do you have your own render method in a custom class?

Comment: Foo is neither controller nor service. It's just regular class used inside controller action. And Yes, it has custom render method

Answer (score 2):

You can also define your own exception controller and perform needed behavior.

Check [How to customize Error Pages](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html) and [Configuration: exception_controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html#config-twig-exception-controller)

**UPD**

Creating event listener is a good solution to catch exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

We can also customize specific TWIG error templates according to the HTTP status ( returned )code. For example, create a app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig template to display a special page for 404 (page not found) errors.

OR, we can also customize [exceptionController](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html#config-twig-exception-controller).